# Android device not being recognized inside Ubuntu running in VirtualBox on Windows 7?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu inside VirtualBox installed on Windows 7. For some reason, when I type `adb devices` after connecting my phone, nothing happens. It just gives me a message saying that no devices were found.

The device is recognized in Windows but under Ubuntu, nothing happens. I tried using sudo but that doesn't work either. Is there anyway to get Ubuntu inside the VM to recognize the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you followed the [instructions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#id321700) for allowing your VM to access host USB devices?

You will then need to follow the guide that user591604 links to, below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a VM, but I develop for android out of ubuntu. I remember having to do some wonky things. There's more about this on this page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: @user591604: +1 for the tip. Thank you for that.

Comment: Link seems broken